# Sending PDF Attachment from URL into Email using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been attempting to send a PDF file from a URL via email. While my code is able to send the email, there seems to be an issue with the attached file, as it arrives corrupted and broken.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from(EMAIL_ADDRESS,EMAIL_NAME);
$this->email->to('test@example.com');
$this->email->subject("Email Subject");
$this->email->message("Please find attached file");
$this->email->attach('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');
$this->email->send();
```

Here is a screenshot of CodeIgniter's official docs. Which tells that we can send attachments from the URL

[image]

Comment: _"Which tells that we can send attachments from the URL"_ - sure, from the CodeIgniter side of things. But whether whatever URL you actually specify, is willing to let itself be "downloaded" by server-side code, might be a different matter. _"as it arrives corrupted and broken"_ - open it in a text or hex editor, and see what you find in there.

Comment: @CBroe it shows nothing just an empty file with 0 bytes.

Comment: Then most likely the URL you used, gave an "empty" response, or an HTTP error. (You need to be aware, that it might not necessarily behave the same way, as when you simply try to request it via your browser.)

Comment: hmm, it appears to be a highly valid reason.